# getting my form to output correctly

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I'm trying to have my form inputs appear in a paragraph, but instead it briefly appears then disappears. Here is my code:

```
<form onSubmit = "submitForm()" name="myForm">
  First Name:<input type="text" name="firstName" /><br />
  Last Name:<input type="text" name="lastName" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value=" Submit " name="submit" />
  </form>

<p id="para">

</p>

function submitForm () {
  var firstName = document.forms["myForm"]["firstName"].value;
  var lastName = document.forms["myForm"]["lastName"].value;
  document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = "Your first name is " + firstName + " and your last name is " + lastName;
}
```

Perhaps the reason it is disappearing immediately has to do with the form itself? But i'm not entirely sure. Any thoughts?

Comment: Submitting a form will cause the page to postback/reload. Try passing the form itself as a parameter to your function `onSubmit="submitForm(this)"`, add the parameter to the function itself `function submitForm(e) { ... }`, block it from refreshing by putting `e.preventDefault()` in the function.

Comment: Is there anyway to stop this from happening? For instance in one tutorial I saw the guy typed 'return false' somewhere.

Comment: Or am I better off just not using the form tag ?

Comment: Is the sole purpose of your code to ask the user for their name and then echo it to the screen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution.

The problem was when you tried to submit your from it's not actually preventing a form's default behavior. So you have to stop your form's default behavior. For that, you have to **return false;** in your function

Here is the demo link [enter link description here](http://codepen.io/Rezwana/pen/XMGGwY)

```
<form action="#" method="POST" name="myForm" onsubmit="return yourFunctionName();">

    First Name:<input type="text" name="firstName" /><br />

    Last Name:<input type="text" name="lastName" /><br />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

<div id="result"></div>

<script>
    function yourFunctionName()
    {           
        var firstName = document.forms["myForm"]["firstName"].value;
        var lastName = document.forms["myForm"]["lastName"].value;

        document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = "Your first name is <b>" + firstName + "</b> and your last name is <b>" + lastName + "</b>";

        return false;

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Do something like the following:

```
<form onSubmit = "return submitForm()" name="myForm">
  First Name:<input type="text" name="firstName" /><br />
  Last Name:<input type="text" name="lastName" /><br />
  <input type="submit" value=" Submit " name="submit" />
  </form>

<p id="para">

</p>
<script>
function submitForm () {
  var firstName = document.forms["myForm"]["firstName"].value;
  var lastName = document.forms["myForm"]["lastName"].value;
  document.getElementById('para').innerHTML = "Your first name is " + firstName + " and your last name is " + lastName;
  return false;
}
  </script>
```

In other words, add `return` to the event i.e `onSubmit = "return submitForm()"` and make the function to return `false` at its end

The disappear is due to the form performs the submit so, we prevent it from submitting the data. Checkout [**this demo**](http://output.jsbin.com/hahepolepe)

Comment: This reads more like a game of spot-the-difference than an answer. What did you change? Why should it make a difference?